# How do I use Home Assistant's Configurator with remote access?

Tags: remote-access, home-assistant

I have:

- Raspberry PI 3 B+
- Hassbian with Home Assistant

And have created my own remote domain. Before I did that, I could easily use Configurator. But now, it just show me the Home Assistant login page in that iframe.

My configuration settings for this are:

```
# Configurator
panel_iframe:
  configurator:
    title: Configurator
    icon: mdi:wrench
    url: https://myhassdomain.com
```

How do I fix so I can access Configurator now?

Answer (score 3):

In the *configuration.py* file, i hope you are using double quotes while parsing string arguments as the output which you are receiving, maximum time we miss those quotes only while changing arguments.
If this doesn't help please go through the appended link:

https://www.home-assistant.io/docs/ecosystem/hass-configurator/#configuration-ui-for-home-assistant

Comment: Yes, I have double quotes everywhere. Could the problem be caused of that I'm running it on Hassbian? Not Hass.io.

Comment: Have you installed tmux with hassbian.The description can be found in the link i have given in my answer. Please let me know